# c# get path for directory in project

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I'm trying get the path of a folder in my project called EmailAttachments.  I tried

```
File.Exists("~/EmailAttachments/TestReport.pdf")
```

but that returns false.  How can I get the path to a directory in the program so I can write files to it and retrieve them later?

This is in asp.net, not winforms

Comment: ASP.NET or Winforms?

Comment: ASP.NET, sorry, forgot to include that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to get the ASP.NET local path, use `Server.MapPath("~/EmailAttachments/TestReport.pdf")` to get its fully qualified path.

Comment: I kinda like using camel and pascal case, but for specific things